# Spring Integration Message Driven channel adapter Refresh Scope

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud

My application is using Spring cloud and Refresh Scope is used to dynamically refresh some of the beans when the configuration is change. How can I make the same behavior applicable to the Jms message listener as well. 
Below is the message listener defined in Spring integration. How can I define this bean to refresh whenever there is a configuration change. In this case I am using the max concurrent consumers and auto-startup attributes to load from properties

```
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
    id="processMessageDrivenChannelAdapter" send-timeout="5000"
    max-messages-per-task="-1"
    idle-task-execution-limit="100"
    max-concurrent-consumers="${consumers}"
    connection-factory="messageConnectionFactory"
    destination="jmsQueue" channel="messageProcessChannel"
    acknowledge="transacted" auto-startup="${autoStartUp}"  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@RefreshScope` is not supported for "active" beans; e.g. those that implement `SmartLifecycle` that need their lifecycle managed (started/stopped etc).

It is only supported for passive beans that just get new properties after a refresh.

You would have to listen for the refresh event and manually stop/reconfigure/start the adapter.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Could you please provide some pointers on how to listen to refresh event from the client application.

Comment: Add an `ApplicationListener<RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent>` bean (or annotate a method on a bean with `@EventListener` with a `RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent` parameter). [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#context-functionality-events).